# How to remove lines containing any matching text in bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a text file.  It looks like this:

```
Business Card: 2x3.5: Recycled 100lb Dull Cover with Matte Finish(Rounded Corners): Color front No Back: 1000: $67.18 :
Business Card: 2x3.5: Recycled 100lb Dull Cover with Matte Finish(Rounded Corners): Color front No Back: 2500: $103.17 :
Business Card: 2x3.5: Recycled 100lb Dull Cover with Matte Finish(Rounded Corners): Color front No Back: 5000: $170.00 :
Business Card: 2x3.5: 14pt Premium Uncoated Cover: Color front B&W back: 250: $42.25 :
Business Card: 2x3.5: 14pt Premium Uncoated Cover: Color front B&W back: 500: $44.00 :
Business Card: 2x3.5: 14pt Premium Uncoated Cover: Color front B&W back: 1000: $54.08 :
Business Card: 2x3.5: 14pt Premium Uncoated Cover: Color front B&W back: 2500: $79.33 :
Business Card: 2x3.5: 14pt Premium Uncoated Cover: Color front B&W back: 5000: $144.33 :
Door Hanger: 3.5x8.5: 100lb Gloss Book with Aqueous Coating (C2S): Color Front No Back: 250: $136.23 :
Door Hanger: 3.5x8.5: 100lb Gloss Book with Aqueous Coating (C2S): Color Front No Back: 500: $159.53 :
Door Hanger: 3.5x8.5: 100lb Gloss Book with Aqueous Coating (C2S): Color Front No Back: 1000: $176.17 :
Door Hanger: 3.5x8.5: 100lb Gloss Book with Aqueous Coating (C2S): Color Front No Back: 2500: $297.58 :
Door Hanger: 3.5x8.5: 100lb Gloss Book with Aqueous Coating (C2S): Color Front No Back: 5000: $522.72 :
Door Hanger: 3.5x8.5: 100lb Gloss Book with Aqueous Coating (C2S): Color Both Sides: 250: $138.70 :
Door Hanger: 3.5x8.5: 100lb Gloss Book with Aqueous Coating (C2S): Color Both Sides: 500: $164.50 :
Door Hanger: 3.5x8.5: 100lb Gloss Book with Aqueous Coating (C2S): Color Both Sides: 1000: $181.13 :
Door Hanger: 3.5x8.5: 100lb Gloss Book with Aqueous Coating (C2S): Color Both Sides: 2500: $302.53 :
Door Hanger: 3.5x8.5: 100lb Gloss Book with Aqueous Coating (C2S): Color Both Sides: 5000: $515.63 :
```

So I have `Business Cards`, and I have `Door Hanger`s.  Each one is an item, but to count them I need to remove every other occurance of them.

So in the end, the file would like this:

```
Business Card: 2x3.5: Recycled 100lb Dull Cover with Matte Finish(Rounded Corners): Color front No Back: 1000: $67.18 :
Door Hanger: 3.5x8.5: 100lb Gloss Book with Aqueous Coating (C2S): Color Front No Back: 250: $136.23 :
```

I have to do this without specifying exact names, that is I can't run `sed` specifically on occurrence of `Business Card` or `Door Hanger`.  I just need to remove all lines containing ANY similarities, not just exact duplicates.

Thanks

Comment: Ok just answered my own question.  In the above example, first remove all text after :, this will leave me with only one word on each line.  Then delete all duplicates.

Comment: Answered thousands of times before `awk -F: '!a[$1]++'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With awk you can do that:

```
awk -F":" '$1!=k{print $0}{k=$1}' file.txt

Business Card: 2x3.5: Recycled 100lb Dull Cover with Matte Finish(Rounded Corners): Color front No Back: 1000: $67.18 :
Door Hanger: 3.5x8.5: 100lb Gloss Book with Aqueous Coating (C2S): Color Front No Back: 250: $136.23 :
```

Where you test whether the first field is equal to the one from the previous line or not. If it's equal do nothing, just save it (`k=$1`), if it's not, print the line.

This can be shortened to:

```
awk -F: '!seen[$1]++' file.txt
```

(Thx to JID and glenn jackman)

Alternatively, if you had fix number of column you could have done:

```
rev file.txt | uniq -f 17 | rev
```

where you reverse each line of your file and skip the 17 first column to apply uniq on the last one (in fact, the first ones), and reverse back. But here it's not very convenient as you don't have the same number of columns.

HTH

Comment: Since `print $0` is the default action, you can write `awk -F: '$1!=k;{k=$1}' file.txt`. And, as JID commented, this is an awk idiom: print the line the first time you see something: `awk -F: '!seen[$1]++' file`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment a simple way to do this would be:

```
cat filename | awk -F ":" '{print $1}' | sort | uniq
```

Comment: You don't need `cat` -- awk can read files. See if your `sort` command has the `-u` option: `awk -F: '{print $1}' filename | sort -u` -- however this does not provide the requested output.